# How can you tab in the first line of a paragraph of text

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some text that is passed dynamically, but the design of the text requires that the top line is tabbed in, so it looks like this:

```
Stackover flow rules, Stackover flow rules,
```

Stackover flow rules, Stackover flow rules, Stackover 
flow rules,

Could I use HTML special characters to do this?

Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enter text that has a "\t" (TAB) character as the first character of the first line. And make sure your textfield has a textformat with tab stops in it.

I did it recently like this:

```
        var tf:TextFormat = _textField.defaultTextFormat;
        tf.tabStops = [20]; // make the indentation 20 px
        _textField.defaultTextFormat = tf;
        _textField.text = "\t"+text;
```

Comment: Also found out that the TextFormat class supports a property called 'indent', which allows you to set the number of pixels the first character in a paragraph is indented.

Comment: That's right. In my case I wanted only to indent the first character of the text. Not again after a line break. That's why I did it like that - not using 'indent'. You'd have to make sure the text doesn't contain any other tabs in my example.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should specify what text container you use. For `p` html tag, there is text-indent property to indent first line. Alternatively, you can use `&nbsp;` characters.